# Avoid Custom Terminals Hiding (Suppressing) Derived Ones

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext, xtend

I started playing around with xtext a few days ago and just went through the tutorials. Maybe the solution has been covered in the reference somewhere but I cannot get it right quickly.

My problem is this. I tried to write a simple grammar which mixed in `org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals` . Then I wanted to insert a cusotm terminal `FILE_NAME` like this:

```
terminal FILE_NAME:
( !('/' | '\\' | ':' | '*' | '?' | '"' | '<' | '>' | '|') )+
;
```

That's basically what a filename is allowed to be under Windows. However, by doing that, inherited rules like ID, INT, etc. would never be matched, because they are always generated after custom terminals.

Can that kind of problem be avoided gracefully (as repeatless as possible and as general as possible)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminal rules (aka lexer rules) are used to tokenize the input sequenze. IMHO there should be a minimum of semantics in terminal rules.

You try to express a specialized parser rule which accepts only valid file names.

Have a look at parser phases described in the Xtext Documentation [1]. My suggestion:

1. Lexing: Instead of using a specialized terminal rule go with STRING.
2. Validation: Write a validation rule for an EClass with a 'fileName' EAttribute.

> as repeatless as possible and as general as possible

You don't want to repeat your validation for every EClass with a 'fileName' EAttribute. Introduce a new super type with a 'fileName' EAttribute if you have a refined Ecore model.

Than you can implement one general validation rule #check_fileName_is_valid(ElementWithFile).

And if you don't have a refined MM use *meta model hints* within your grammar. If you provide a generalized super type Xtext's Ecore inferrer will pull up common features of the subtypes. Ex:

```
ElementWithFile: A | B;
A: ... 'file' fileName=STRING ...;
B: ... 'file' fileName=STRING ...;
// => Ecore: ElementWithFile.fileName<EString>
```

[1] http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#DSL

Comment: Thanks Alex! I am doing roughly what you have suggested. However, it is a workaround rather than a solution. If I want to use xtext to create an editor for an existing grammar that I cannot modify the grammar, it would not work. An real world example is the name of the material defined by the ogre3d material scripts: http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_14.html#Material-Scripts

Comment: Actually it is one possible solution.  
  
The other way requires some additionally setup. 
Especially if the grammar is fixed or you don't want to pollute it with that kind of hints refine the Ecore model behind your grammar:
  
* Go to src-gen of your DSL runtime plugin and grab YourDSL.ecore and YourDSL.genmodel.  
* Move the MM resources to a new "com.your.dsl.model" plug-in. 
* Modify the YourDSL.ecore as required.  
* Generate the model code from GenModel.  
* Make sure the model plug-in exports the right packages of the model code.  
(tbc ...)

Comment: ...
* Make sure the runtime/ui/test/generator/... plug-ins declare a dependency to the model plug-in.  
* Use import "YourDslURL" instead of generate "YourDslURL".
  
This way you are responsible for the compatibility of Ecore model and Xtext grammar. 
The grammar editor will show your warnings/errors if there are problems.

There is also a way to generate model code by execution of a MWE2 workflow.

Comment: Hi, Alex. I haven't find time to test what you suggested. I will get back to you soon. Thanks again.